# Error Code: 1822 when data types are matching, with composite key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

Getting an

> Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing
>   index for constraint 'subject_ibfk_1' in the referenced table
>   'enrolment'

when attempting to create the `subject` table. The problem is, the error does not occur on the previous table `student`. The data types are the same, and the primary keys are defined.

This error occurs for both the `enrolment` and `grade` tables.

```
create table enrolment(
    stud_id char(9) not null,
    subj_code char(8) not null,
    semester tinyint unsigned not null,
    year smallint unsigned not null,
    comment text,

    primary key (stud_id, subj_code, semester, year)
);

create table grade(
    stud_id char(9) not null,
    subj_code char(8) not null,
    semester tinyint unsigned not null,
    year smallint unsigned not null,
    grade tinyint unsigned,

    primary key (stud_id, subj_code, semester, year)
);

create table student(
    stud_id char(9) not null,
    stud_name char(30),
    stud_phone char(12),
    stud_date_of_birth date,
    stud_city char(26),
    stud_address char(30),
    stud_postcode char(4),

    primary key (stud_id),

    foreign key (stud_id)
        references grade(stud_id),
    foreign key (stud_id)
        references enrolment(stud_id)
);

create table subject(
    subj_code char(8) not null,
    subj_title char(40),

    primary key (subj_code),

    foreign key (subj_code)
        references enrolment(subj_code),

    foreign key (subj_code)
        references grade(subj_code)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to the fact that the foreign key, `subj_code`, is part of a *multi-column* primary key (PK) in the referenced table `enrolment`:

```
primary key (stud_id, subj_code, semester, year)
```

where this column (`subj_code`) is *not the leftmost one*.

Table `student` does not have this problem because its foreign key column `stud_id` is the leftmost column of the PK in the referenced table.

To resolve this you can create a new index for the referened column:

```
ALTER TABLE enrolment ADD INDEX subj_code_idx (subj_code);
```

**Note:** You have to do the same for referenced table `grade` in the other foreign key.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6f423)

Comment: This works, but why does creating a new index for the column solve the problem?

Comment: Thank you, this is the right answer

Answer (score 0):

> FOREIGN KEY of one table is a PRIMARY key of another table. its a mapping key or column between two table.

First of all: you don't make subject_id as primary key in CLO table.
subject_id is act as a primary key in subject table and foreign key in clo table

```
ALTER TABLE `clo` DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(`clo_id`);

ALTER TABLE `subject` DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(`subject_id`);

ALTER TABLE clo ADD FOREIGN KEY (subject_id) REFERENCES subject(subject_id)
```

[image]

[image]